# Google Script 'replace' function with range

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script

I'm trying to script a "roman-number-to-decimal-number" function in Google Spreadsheets.
So far I've managed to make it work using the code below:

```
function rom2num(inputRange) {
inputRange = inputRange.replace(/\bi\b/gi,1); //convert 'I' to '1'
  return inputRange;
}
```

This works perfectly when the input is one cell only. However, whenever I try to input a range (A1:B2) I get the error: "cannot find function replace in object".

Some examples of what I want to achieve:

```
Column A      | Column with function
i, ii, iii    | 1, 2, 3
Godfather II  | Godfather 2
iv, v, vi     | 4, 5, 6
Star Wars V   | Star Wars 5
```

I could just choose to repeat the function in the cells below, as Crayon suggested, however, the range that needs to be reformatted might be 50 rows, or it might be 100 rows and I prefer not throwing in 50 extra instances of the function if they're not to be used. I want it to be as automatic as possible. :-)

I know that it's possible to retrieve the information on a range of cells, and the return that information in another range of cells just by using the following code:

```
function copyRange(inputRange) {
return inputRange;
}
```

So to input a range and output the same range isn't a problem. The problem is trying to incorporate the replace-function. I have managed to alter the information in the whole range using the 'toString()'-function. And then I was able to to split the output over several columns using 'split(",")' but I don't want it to spread across columns, just rows.

So if I somehow could convert the range/array to a string and then back to a range/array...

Is it possible to achieve this without bloating the code too much? (I'm a newbie scripter and prefer my scripts short, like my example above.)

I'm sorry if i'm being unclear. I'm used to look up answers in forums like this but not asking the questions myself!

Thanks!

**EDIT: finally realized things were getting a bit too complicated so I just went with Crayons advice and used the 'dragging'-method. Saved me a lot of hazzle. Thanks for the help!!**

Comment: So what *is* in that `inputRange` variable then, if it's not a string? Please add the type (as reported by `typeof inputRange`) and the contents of that variable. This isn't a Google Script problem at all, just straightforward JavaScript, but it's hard to help without knowing what's in that variable. :-)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick response. I've edited the post to hopefully bring more clarity to the situation and answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: Whoa, that's way too much detail now. :-) Really, you're making this too complicated. Let's start over. You have a function. It takes an input and converts to an output. What, exactly, is that input? What output should it generate from that input? Give specific examples for both, as many examples as it takes to show the different cases you may encounter but no more. Forget about the spreadsheets API and everything else, that's all just a distraction. Get to the the bare minimum specific requirements for this particular function, and then you have something that's easy to solve.

Comment: Of course, I may be *oversimplifying* here! Take a look at Crayon's answer for some valuable information. My real point is to separate out the two problems: 1) how do you interact with the spreadsheets API in the way you need, and 2) how do you write a JavaScript function that does the transformation you need. If you can separate out those two questions it may be easier to analyze the problem.

Comment: Haha thanks for baring with me and trying to solve my problem. Well, in the Google Spreadsheet document I can open a script editor. In the editor I can declare a function and it looks exactly like my first code example above. Then to call my function in Spreadsheets I just type (in a cell) =rom2num(input). (The input can be some text or a reference to another cell or another range of cells.

Comment: And I think the problem lies in the interaction with the spreadsheet, as I need to return multiple rows in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions your function can only alter data in the cell the function is invoked in, so you shouldn't be trying to change multiple cells anyways.  You should have the function do the replace for that cell and then apply the function to multiple cells.

For example

```
A  B
i  =rom2num(A1)
i
i
i
```

This will make B1 equal to "1".  Now hold your mouse over B1 and on the bottom-right is the dot point, drag down to B4 and you will see the function applied to rows B2-4.

**edit:**

In light of your comment and additional info in your question, I think I know what you're trying to do. Basically you want to exploit overflowing the value to the cells to effectively act on multiple cells.  So yeah, this is possible by returning a double array.  Your new example shows [converting roman numerals to actual numbers](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-roman-numeral-converter)..well it's a bit more complex than simply doing a `.replace` but you should be able to figure out how to work that stuff into what you're trying to do, once you figure out how to get the values to work on!  So here is how to do that:

```
function rom2num(inputRange) {
  var cells = [];
  for (var i=0;i<inputRange.length;i++) {
    cells[i] = [String(inputRange[i]).replace(/i/gi,1)];
  }
  return cells;
}
```

This example here iterates through each row in the range and simply replaces "i" with "1".  It then returns a double array of the values, so for instance if you have

```
A              B
i, ii, iii     =rom2num(A1:A4)
Godfather II
iv, v, vi
Star Wars V
```

The function will return and overflow the cells to look like this:

```
A               B
i, ii, iii      1, 11, 111
Godfather II    Godfather 11
iv, v, vi       1v, v, v1
Star Wars V     Star Wars V
```

Like I said, you'll have to do more than just `.replace` (go to the link I gave you) to actually convert the roman numbers to numberals, but as far as to your actual question, this should do it.

**edit 2:**

I actually went ahead and incorporated the roman numeral conversion function into it because I wanted to see it. So I thought may as well share with you the final script:

```
function rom2num(inputRange) {
  var cells = [];
  for (var i=0;i<inputRange.length;i++) {
    cells[i] = [
      String(inputRange[i]).replace(/\b([ivxcldm]+)\b/gi,function(p,p1) {
        return deromanize(p1); 
      })
    ];
  }
  return cells;
}

function deromanize (str) {
    var str = str.toUpperCase(),
        validator = /^M*(?:D?C{0,3}|C[MD])(?:L?X{0,3}|X[CL])(?:V?I{0,3}|I[XV])$/,
        token = /[MDLV]|C[MD]?|X[CL]?|I[XV]?/g,
        key = {M:1000,CM:900,D:500,CD:400,C:100,XC:90,L:50,XL:40,X:10,IX:9,V:5,IV:4,I:1},
        num = 0, m;
    if (!(str && validator.test(str)))
        return false;
    while (m = token.exec(str))
        num += key[m[0]];
    return num;
}
```

Same thing as before...column A has the stuff you want to act on, put your `=rom2num(A1:A4)` in first cell of column B.  This will put the converted roman numerals into each cell of column B, lined up with column A cells.  But remember, it's not actually changing individual An > Bn cells..it's really grabbing the range you specify and overflowing the results into multiple cells. It effectively does what you want, but it's not exactly the same thing.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for pointing me to that page. It contained some information about returning arrays which may be what I have to do. Actually I'm not trying do change the original data, I just want to retrieve the data, then output a variation of that in another cell. The reason for not wanting to use the 'drag'-method is that the content in the original range may change and contain either more or fewer rows.

Comment: Hey @user2268171 thanks for the comment and also update to your question.  I think I understand what you're trying to do now and have updated my answer to reflect it.  Hope this helps!

Comment: @user2268171 I updated my answer again. I was curious to see an end solution so I went ahead and added the roman numeral conversion function.  Since I did it, I figured may as well save you the trouble.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! I tried your code and it does exactly what I was asking for. I need to study it later to find out exactly what's going on. One thing though, if the data range is spread over multiple columns the result will still be one column only, but it separates the content with commas. I tried using the SPLIT()-function in spreadsheets but for some reason it won't accept the comma. :-S This isn't really a problem since my data involves one column only, but for future purposes it might be needed to make it multicolumn-compatible. I'll let you know if I find a solution. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

I used a more succinct approach:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
sh
  .getRange('A:B')
  .createTextFinder('i')
  .replaceAllWith('1')
```