# Find and replace range of cells [Example Script]

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an example script running a find and replace of values with the script.

I am wondering how I will need to adapt this existing script to find a range of cells to replace the text with [not specifying the text in the script, but running through a column of values to find instead, with a second column notating what to replace it with].

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zmY48XQT_esYji58pMbk7oJy6Vncr0Oh5urJiK3ka4U/edit#gid=0

This is the closest I could fine to my query, but am unable to replicate [loops are not my strongpoint]

[Google Script 'replace' function with range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937947/google-script-replace-function-with-range)

```
 function runReplaceInSheet(){
      var sheet = 
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      //  get the current data range values as an array
      //  Fewer calls to access the sheet -> lower overhead 
      var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

      // Replace Staff Names
      replaceInSheet(values, 'This is a sentence.', 'This is a word');
      replaceInSheet(values, 'Hello my name is', 'Your name is');
      replaceInSheet(values, '.', '-');
      replaceInSheet(values, '!', '.');
      replaceInSheet(values, 'Bob', 'Sagget');

      // Write all updated values to the sheet, at once
      sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);
    }

    function replaceInSheet(values, to_replace, replace_with) {
      //loop over the rows in the array
      for(var row in values){
      //use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the 
      row.
      var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value) {
      return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with);
    });

    //replace the original row values with the replaced values
      values[row] = replaced_values;
      }
    }
```

I would like the script to find the contents within cells D21:D23 thoughout all the sheet, and replace any instance with E21:E23

Comment: Try to edit this question to a specific question that includes things that you have tried and specific issues you are facing. Be sure and  read https://stackoverflow.com/tour  and there is some good info on asking a good question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. For this question remove the google example and replace it with the code you have attempted to write to solve your problem. Also try to narrow your question down. Do you have a question about loops? Tell us what that question is. Just telling us you are not good with loops does not help us write a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function findAndReplaceOnAllSheets() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    shts[i].getRange('D21:D23').setValues(shts[i].getRange('E21:E23').getValues());
  }
}
```

I guess I don't understand your question.

What does all this mean?

[image]

> If you want to give us an example show us the text before the change and after the change and be clear about which is which.

Comment: Thank you Cooper.

Instead of replacing the cells in the spreadsheet, is there a way to find the column values D in the spreadsheet in a Google Doc, [replaced with the values in F]?

Comment: For example [Google Doc key]: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xwhahNVKpY2uNV-YEG-snWBkqj4T45_Xa7vr1Cb1S9w/edit

[Google Sheet of values needing change]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zmY48XQT_esYji58pMbk7oJy6Vncr0Oh5urJiK3ka4U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You said `I would like the script to find the contents within cells D21:D23 thoughout all the sheet, and replace any instance with E21:E23`...No mention of F

Comment: Sorry I meant E. Replaced with the values in E. Sheets would not take my 50000 character/100000 line limit. Its a book I am trying edit, and just realized Google Docs has a script function too.

Comment: Why did you choose to write a book in a spreadsheet as opposed to say Google Document?